# Issues with downloading (Viewer Discretion is advised) videos on YouTube with PyTube

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I have been creating a program to grab links from a YouTube playlist and download the individual links but I noticed if you try to download a video that has a "Viewer Discretion is Advised" warning label attached to the video I get an error that reads "Streaming Error"

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist
import os

#---------------------------------------------
youtube = True
is_playlist = False
convert_to_mp3 = True
youtube_playlist_name = "Folder Name"
youtube_playlist_videos = [""]
#---------------------------------------------
spotify = False
spotify_playlist_name = ""
spotify_playlist = [""]
#---------------------------------------------

def download_and_convert_video(link, playlist_name, x, urls):
    video = link.streams.get_audio_only()
    out_file = video.download(output_path=f"audio/{playlist_name}")
    base = os.path.splitext(out_file)
    new_file = f"{base[0]}.mp3"
    print(f"Downloading \"{new_file[new_file.find(playlist_name) + len(playlist_name) + 1:len(new_file)]}\" - {x+1}/{len(urls)}")
    os.rename(out_file, new_file)

def obtain_urls(playlists):
    urls, x  = [], 0
    print("Locating videos in playlist")
    for playlist in playlists:
        playlist_urls = Playlist(playlist)
        for url in playlist_urls:
            x += 1
            urls.append(url)
    print(f"{x} video(s) located")
    return urls

def download_from_youtube(playlist, playlist_name, convert_to_mp3, is_playlist):
    if is_playlist == True:
        urls = obtain_urls(playlist)
    if is_playlist == False:
        urls = playlist

    for x in range(len(urls)):
        if convert_to_mp3 == True:
            download_and_convert_video(YouTube(urls[x]), playlist_name, x, urls)
        if convert_to_mp3 == False:
            download_video(YouTube(urls[x]), playlist_name)
    print(f"Successfully downloaded {len(urls)} video(s)")

def download_video(video, playlist_name):
    video = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download(f"video/{playlist_name}")

if youtube == True:
    download_from_youtube(youtube_playlist_videos, youtube_playlist_name, convert_to_mp3, is_playlist)
```

Comment: I was wondering if there wasn't a way to fix the problem if there was a way to skip videos tagged with that and display a message to the console that we skipped the video.

Comment: By *Viewer Discretion is Advised*, do you mean *Sign in to confirm your age
This video may be inappropriate for some users.* as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHOQYmlCcr8) ? If not, please share us a video id where *Viewer Discretion is Advised*.

Comment: I have a link to the image here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p3Z3HUnjCFfFYnToBSA6YabKoxmIHOWW/view?usp=sharing I do have a way around it now if there isnt a solution but I still would like a way of downloading the video

Comment: Please share a video id of such a *Viewer Discretion is Advised* otherwise I can't try things on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I found this video [`k8jw3JVfK0w`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8jw3JVfK0w) with the *The following content may contain suicide or self-harm topics.
Viewer discretion is advised. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802245)* you mentioned, with [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) downloading this video works fine, please give it a try.